# Cannot drag file into minimized Google Chrome browser

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

With the previous windows 10 version I used to be able to drag my PDF files into a minimized Google Chrome browser which would automatically maximize for me to be able to complete my drag into the browser but now after I made a mistake of updating it to the latest version, it doesn't allow this drag drop feature.

[image]
.
.

So I need to do this tedious workaround of un-maximizing the browser and moving it a bit around as shown below so I can drag it into it. Is there a way how to resolve this or is this a new bug they introduced?

[image]

Comment: oh i found it, they dropped the support. bad move, and the feature drop does not make sense lol https://www.minitool.com/news/drag-and-drop-not-working-windows-11.html

Comment: Yeah, honestly I would move back to Windows 10. Too many mistakes made in 11.